# Magento yoast landing pages

Tags: magento

I've installed Yoast Landing pages extensions for Magento via Magento Connect.

But I can't get it to work.

Magento 1.7 Community

url: http://temporarysite.nl/index.php/stiga/

Code in CMS page ( I tried 3 versions and last the regular category filter block to see if it works at all)

```
Hier komen producten

{{block type="Yoast_Filter/Result" name="filter_result" template="catalog/product   /list.phtml" attribute="manufacturer" value="5" }}

{{block type="Yoast_Filter/Result" name="filter_result" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

Of hier {{block type="Yoast_Filter/result" name="cms_product_listing" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" category="10" }}

Dit is de standaard code {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_listing" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" category_id="10" }}
```